# JavaScript for auto click a submit button

Tags: javascript

Please provide JavaScript to auto click the submit button:
 Here is the sample form: There is no 'id' tag in 'form' and 'button'

```
<form action="?" method="post" >                    

     <div style="display: inline-block;">
        <input type="submit" value="Claim" >
    </div>   
 </form>
```

Comment: SO does not provide code on demand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the `.click()` method of the button:

```js
// This code is just here to demonstrate the the submit button will
// wind up getting its click event triggerd and because it is a submit
// button, that will trigger the submit event of the form.
document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("submit", function(evt){
  evt.preventDefault();
  alert("You triggered the click event of the button!");
});

// Just call the .click method of the button
document.querySelector("input[type='submit']").click();
```

```html
<form action="?" method="post" >                    
 <div style="display: inline-block;">
   <input type="submit" value="Claim" >
 </div>   
</form>
```

But, if your real goal is to trigger the `submit` event of the form, you can bypass the `click` event of the submit button and directly submit the form with:

```
document.querySelector("form").submit();
```